# how to upload a recorded audio file using pdo to a website folder

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, pdo

I am trying to implement an audio recorder within my website. What I want is to make the user save the recorded file directly to the database and/or to a subfolder in my website (called /speaking_audios). There follows the main files: recorder.php, sync.html, upload.php, js/main.js, js/swfobject.js, js/recorder.js, recorder.swf (I don't know what it is for).

recorder.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FlashWavRecorder demo</title>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/recorder.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h1><a href="https://github.com/cykod/FlashWavRecorder">FlashWavRecorder</a></h1>
    <p><strong>Upload requires php, i.e. example will not work on github.com</strong></p>


    <div id="recorder-audio" class="control_panel idle">
      <button class="record_button" onclick="FWRecorder.record('audio', 'audio.wav');" title="Record">
        <img src="images/record.png" alt="Record"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_recording_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopRecording('audio');" title="Stop Recording">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Recording"/>
      </button>
      <button class="play_button" onclick="FWRecorder.playBack('audio');" title="Play">
          <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play"/>
      </button>
      <button class="pause_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.pausePlayBack('audio');" title="Pause Playing">
          <img src="images/pause.png" alt="Pause Playing"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopPlayBack();" title="Stop Playing">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Playing"/>
      </button>
      <div class="level"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="recorder-audio2" class="control_panel idle">
      <button class="record_button" onclick="FWRecorder.record('audio2', 'audio2.wav');" title="Record">
        <img src="images/record.png" alt="Record"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_recording_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopRecording('audio2');" title="Stop Recording">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Recording"/>
      </button>
      <button class="play_button" onclick="FWRecorder.playBack('audio2');" title="Play">
        <img src="images/play.png" alt="Play"/>
      </button>
      <button class="pause_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.pausePlayBack('audio2');" title="Pause Playing">
        <img src="images/pause.png" alt="Pause Playing"/>
      </button>
      <button class="stop_playing_button" onclick="FWRecorder.stopPlayBack();" title="Stop Playing">
        <img src="images/stop.png" alt="Stop Playing"/>
      </button>
      <div class="level"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="details">
      <button class="show_level" onclick="FWRecorder.observeLevel();">Show Level</button>
      <button class="hide_level" onclick="FWRecorder.stopObservingLevel();" style="display: none;">Hide Level</button>
      <span id="save_button">
        <span id="flashcontent">
          <p>Your browser must have JavaScript enabled and the Adobe Flash Player installed.</p>
        </span>
      </span>
      <div><button class="show_settings" onclick="microphonePermission()">Microphone permission</button></div>
      <div id="status">
       Recorder Status...
      </div>
      <div>Duration: <span id="duration"></span></div>
      <div>Activity Level: <span id="activity_level"></span></div>
      <div>Upload status: <span id="upload_status"></span></div>
    </div>

    <form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="upload.php">
      <input name="authenticity_token" value="xxxxx" type="hidden">
      <input name="upload_file[parent_id]" value="1" type="hidden">
      <input name="format" value="json" type="hidden">
    </form>

    <h4>Configure Microphone</h4>
    <form class="mic_config" onsubmit="return false;">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="rate">Rate</label>
          <select id="rate" name="rate">
            <option value="44" selected>44,100 Hz</option>
            <option value="22">22,050 Hz</option>
            <option value="11">11,025 Hz</option>
            <option value="8">8,000 Hz</option>
            <option value="5">5,512 Hz</option>
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="gain">Gain</label>
          <select id="gain" name="gain">
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="silenceLevel">Silence Level</label>
          <select id="silenceLevel" name="silenceLevel">
          </select>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label for="silenceTimeout">Silence Timeout</label>
          <input id="silenceTimeout" name="silenceTimeout" value="2000"/>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input id="useEchoSuppression" name="useEchoSuppression" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="useEchoSuppression">Use Echo Suppression</label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <input id="loopBack" name="loopBack" type="checkbox"/>
          <label for="loopBack">Loop Back</label>
        </li>

        <li>
          <button onclick="configureMicrophone();">Configure</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

upload.php

```
    <?php
$save_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . "/speaking_audios";
if(! file_exists($save_folder)) {
  if(! mkdir($save_folder)) {
    die("failed to create save folder $save_folder");
  }
 }

function valid_wav_file($file) {
  $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
  $header = fread($handle, 4);
  list($chunk_size) = array_values(unpack('V', fread($handle, 4)));
  $format = fread($handle, 4);
  fclose($handle);
  return $header == 'RIFF' && $format == 'WAVE' && $chunk_size == (filesize($file) - 8);
}

$key = 'filename';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
$upload_name = $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"][$key];
$type = $_FILES["upload_file"]["type"][$key];
$filename = "$save_folder/$upload_name";
$saved = 0;
if($type == 'audio/wav' && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.wav$/', $upload_name) && valid_wav_file($tmp_name)) {
  $saved = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $filename) ? 1 : 0;
}

if($_POST['format'] == 'json') {
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  print "{\"saved\": $saved}";
} else {
  print $saved ? "Saved" : 'Not saved';
}

exit;
?>
```

js/main.js

```
    $(function () {
  var $uploadStatus = $('#upload_status'),
    $showLevelButton = $('.show_level'),
    $hideLevelButton = $('.hide_level'),
    $level = $('.control_panel .level');

  var CLASS_CONTROLS = "control_panel";
  var CLASS_RECORDING = "recording";
  var CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY = "playback_ready";
  var CLASS_PLAYING = "playing";
  var CLASS_PLAYBACK_PAUSED = "playback_paused";

//  Embedding flash object ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  setUpFormOptions();
  var appWidth = 24;
  var appHeight = 24;
  var flashvars = {'upload_image': 'images/upload.png'};
  var params = {};
  var attributes = {'id': "recorderApp", 'name': "recorderApp"};
  swfobject.embedSWF("recorder.swf", "flashcontent", appWidth, appHeight, "11.0.0", "", flashvars, params, attributes);

//  Handling FWR events ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  window.fwr_event_handler = function fwr_event_handler() {
    $('#status').text("Last recorder event: " + arguments[0]);
    var name, $controls;
    switch (arguments[0]) {
      case "ready":
        var width = parseInt(arguments[1]);
        var height = parseInt(arguments[2]);
        FWRecorder.uploadFormId = "#uploadForm";
        FWRecorder.uploadFieldName = "upload_file[filename]";
        FWRecorder.connect("recorderApp", 0);
        FWRecorder.recorderOriginalWidth = width;
        FWRecorder.recorderOriginalHeight = height;
        $('.save_button').css({'width': width, 'height': height});
        break;

      case "no_microphone_found":
        break;

      case "microphone_user_request":
        recorderEl().addClass("floating");
        FWRecorder.showPermissionWindow();
        break;

      case "microphone_connected":
        FWRecorder.isReady = true;
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#000'});
        break;

      case "permission_panel_closed":
        FWRecorder.defaultSize();
        recorderEl().removeClass("floating");
        break;

      case "microphone_activity":
        $('#activity_level').text(arguments[1]);
        break;

      case "recording":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        FWRecorder.hide();
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_RECORDING);
        break;

      case "recording_stopped":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        var duration = arguments[2];
        FWRecorder.show();
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY);
        $('#duration').text(duration.toFixed(4) + " seconds");
        break;

      case "microphone_level":
        $level.css({width: arguments[1] * 50 + '%'});
        break;

      case "observing_level":
        $showLevelButton.hide();
        $hideLevelButton.show();
        break;

      case "observing_level_stopped":
        $showLevelButton.show();
        $hideLevelButton.hide();
        $level.css({width: 0});
        break;

      case "playing":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYING);
        break;

      case "playback_started":
        name = arguments[1];
        var latency = arguments[2];
        break;

      case "stopped":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_READY);
        break;

      case "playing_paused":
        name = arguments[1];
        $controls = controlsEl(name);
        setControlsClass($controls, CLASS_PLAYBACK_PAUSED);
        break;

      case "save_pressed":
        FWRecorder.updateForm();
        break;

      case "saving":
        name = arguments[1];
        break;

      case "saved":
        name = arguments[1];
        var data = $.parseJSON(arguments[2]);
        if (data.saved) {
          $('#upload_status').css({'color': '#0F0'}).text(name + " was saved");
        } else {
          $('#upload_status').css({'color': '#F00'}).text(name + " was not saved");
        }
        break;

      case "save_failed":
        name = arguments[1];
        var errorMessage = arguments[2];
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#F00'}).text(name + " failed: " + errorMessage);
        break;

      case "save_progress":
        name = arguments[1];
        var bytesLoaded = arguments[2];
        var bytesTotal = arguments[3];
        $uploadStatus.css({'color': '#000'}).text(name + " progress: " + bytesLoaded + " / " + bytesTotal);
        break;
    }
  };

//  Helper functions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  function setUpFormOptions() {
    var gain = $('#gain')[0];
    var silenceLevel = $('#silenceLevel')[0];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
      gain.options[gain.options.length] = new Option(100 - i);
      silenceLevel.options[silenceLevel.options.length] = new Option(i);
    }
  }

  function setControlsClass($controls, className) {
    $controls.attr('class', CLASS_CONTROLS + ' ' + className);
  }

  function controlsEl(name) {
    return $('#recorder-' + name);
  }

  function recorderEl() {
    return $('#recorderApp');
  }


//  Button actions -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  window.microphonePermission = function () {
    recorderEl().addClass("floating");
    FWRecorder.showPermissionWindow({permanent: true});
  };

  window.configureMicrophone = function () {
    if (!FWRecorder.isReady) {
      return;
    }
    FWRecorder.configure($('#rate').val(), $('#gain').val(), $('#silenceLevel').val(), $('#silenceTimeout').val());
    FWRecorder.setUseEchoSuppression($('#useEchoSuppression').is(":checked"));
    FWRecorder.setLoopBack($('#loopBack').is(":checked"));
  };

});
```

js/recorder.js

```
    (function(global) {
  var Recorder;

  var RECORDED_AUDIO_TYPE = "audio/wav";

  Recorder = {
    recorder: null,
    recorderOriginalWidth: 0,
    recorderOriginalHeight: 0,
    uploadFormId: null,
    uploadFieldName: null,
    isReady: false,

    connect: function(name, attempts) {
      if(navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        Recorder.recorder = window[name];
      } else {
        Recorder.recorder = document[name];
      }

      if(attempts >= 40) {
        return;
      }

      // flash app needs time to load and initialize
      if(Recorder.recorder && Recorder.recorder.init) {
        Recorder.recorderOriginalWidth = Recorder.recorder.width;
        Recorder.recorderOriginalHeight = Recorder.recorder.height;
        if(Recorder.uploadFormId && $) {
          var frm = $(Recorder.uploadFormId); 
          Recorder.recorder.init(frm.attr('action').toString(), Recorder.uploadFieldName, frm.serializeArray());
        }
        return;
      }

      setTimeout(function() {Recorder.connect(name, attempts+1);}, 100);
    },

    playBack: function(name) {
      // TODO: Rename to `playback`
      Recorder.recorder.playBack(name);
    },

    pausePlayBack: function(name) {
      // TODO: Rename to `pausePlayback`
      Recorder.recorder.pausePlayBack(name);
    },

    playBackFrom: function(name, time) {
      // TODO: Rename to `playbackFrom`
      Recorder.recorder.playBackFrom(name, time);
    },

    record: function(name, filename) {
      Recorder.recorder.record(name, filename);
    },

    stopRecording: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.stopRecording();
    },

    stopPlayBack: function() {
      // TODO: Rename to `stopPlayback`
      Recorder.recorder.stopPlayBack();
    },

    observeLevel: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.observeLevel();
    },

    stopObservingLevel: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.stopObservingLevel();
    },

    observeSamples: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.observeSamples();
    },

    stopObservingSamples: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.stopObservingSamples();
    },

    resize: function(width, height) {
      Recorder.recorder.width = width + "px";
      Recorder.recorder.height = height + "px";
    },

    defaultSize: function() {
      Recorder.resize(Recorder.recorderOriginalWidth, Recorder.recorderOriginalHeight);
    },

    show: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.show();
    },

    hide: function() {
      Recorder.recorder.hide();
    },

    duration: function(name) {
      // TODO: rename to `getDuration`
      return Recorder.recorder.duration(name || Recorder.uploadFieldName);
    },

    getBase64: function(name) {
      var data = Recorder.recorder.getBase64(name);
      return 'data:' + RECORDED_AUDIO_TYPE + ';base64,' + data;
    },

    getBlob: function(name) {
      var base64Data = Recorder.getBase64(name).split(',')[1];
      return base64toBlob(base64Data, RECORDED_AUDIO_TYPE);
    },

    getCurrentTime: function(name) {
        return Recorder.recorder.getCurrentTime(name);
    },

    isMicrophoneAccessible: function() {
      return Recorder.recorder.isMicrophoneAccessible();
    },

    updateForm: function() {
      var frm = $(Recorder.uploadFormId); 
      Recorder.recorder.update(frm.serializeArray());
    },

    showPermissionWindow: function(options) {
      Recorder.resize(240, 160);
      // need to wait until app is resized before displaying permissions screen
      var permissionCommand = function() {
        if (options && options.permanent) {
          Recorder.recorder.permitPermanently();
        } else {
          Recorder.recorder.permit();
        }
      };
      setTimeout(permissionCommand, 1);
    },

    configure: function(rate, gain, silenceLevel, silenceTimeout) {
      rate = parseInt(rate || 22);
      gain = parseInt(gain || 100);
      silenceLevel = parseInt(silenceLevel || 0);
      silenceTimeout = parseInt(silenceTimeout || 4000);
      switch(rate) {
      case 44:
      case 22:
      case 11:
      case 8:
      case 5:
        break;
      default:
        throw("invalid rate " + rate);
      }

      if(gain < 0 || gain > 100) {
        throw("invalid gain " + gain);
      }

      if(silenceLevel < 0 || silenceLevel > 100) {
        throw("invalid silenceLevel " + silenceLevel);
      }

      if(silenceTimeout < -1) {
        throw("invalid silenceTimeout " + silenceTimeout);
      }

      Recorder.recorder.configure(rate, gain, silenceLevel, silenceTimeout);
    },

    setUseEchoSuppression: function(val) {
      if(typeof(val) != 'boolean') {
        throw("invalid value for setting echo suppression, val: " + val);
      }

      Recorder.recorder.setUseEchoSuppression(val);
    },

    setLoopBack: function(val) {
      if(typeof(val) != 'boolean') {
        throw("invalid value for setting loop back, val: " + val);
      }

      Recorder.recorder.setLoopBack(val);
    }
  };

  function base64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
      var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

      var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
      }

      var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
      byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    return new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
  }


  global.FWRecorder = Recorder;


})(this);
```

Well, I just want you to concentrate on the upload.php file and see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - I also don't see any SQL here. check your form.

Comment: So far, I just want to understand how to save this file to a subfolder, not to the database.

Comment: your form's missing an enctype.

Comment: Sort of like `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ? in which form?

Comment: for `<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="upload.php">` and a POST method is also required if your code doesn't have any yet. Therefore `<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and check for errors and making sure the folder you're uploading to, has the right permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it.

Comment: great, I can post it as an answer and you can accept it. It will mark it as solved. I will also add a few more bits to it.

Comment: ok, soon I'll post another related question, but this time it will concern saving this same file to the database and user identification or output for play. Something more or less like that... I'm Brazilian, that's why my English is so bad.

Comment: No problemo ;-) it has been posted below. Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with files, a valid enctype and a POST method is required.

Therefore, you need to change this form:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="upload.php">
```

To this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" action="upload.php">
```

and check for errors and making sure the folder you're uploading to, has the right permissions.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Can u indicate me any tutorial teaching the relationship between the files and the clients. That is, how can I identify the files and relate it to a certain user so that it appears on the member's page?

Comment: @RogerioBritoSoares http://stackoverflow.com/a/7255273/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/28294645/ this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/13214602/ I hope this helps.

Comment: What would you recommend? Uploading files to database or subfolder?

Comment: @RogerioBritoSoares That is up to you. Usually, people tend to upload files to a folder and then referencing with a link to the file. If your database gets corrupted or lost, then you need to start over. It's a double-edged sword issue. Both have their pros and cons. Using BLOB will greatly increase your dB size also.

Comment: I'd like you to have a look at https://www.fiverr.com/roguitar/solve-any-php-issues-on-your-website?context=advanced_search&context_type=new&context_referrer=search_gigs&pos=1&funnel=b0a7788e-ad86-44bf-b3bf-c56c0225abcc . I need some tips for freelancing and web marketing. Do you know any website or someone on the internet who can help me?