# Using end() with explode() does not work

Tags: php, arrays, string, split

I have a string which will contain a file upload name, for example "image.jpg".
I'm trying to use the explode function but it's returning an error "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in..."

I've tried  looking for reasons why and comparing it to how use is instructed on PHP.Net but to no avail.

```
$upload_extension = end(explode(".", $feature_icon));
```

Comment: Show us how you define `$feature_icon`

Comment: `$feature_icon` should be a string, not an array.

Comment: You may want to consider pathinfo() anyway...

Comment: $feature_icon is just a string of the name a file has been uploaded. It's a simple $feature_icon = $_GET['feature_icon'];

Comment: @user2332946, can you show us the result of a `var_dump($_GET['feature_icon']);` ?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "image.jpg" }

Comment: @user2332946 Keep in mind, that you'll need to validate the type of `$_GET['feature_icon']` to string anyway. If someone posts against your page with controls named `feature_icon[]`, it'll auto-create an array, and you'll be passing that to explode, yielding errors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can not use [**`end()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) like you are doing since

> [`end()` -> Parameters ¶](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) The array. This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

so do like

```
$feature_icon ="image.jpg";
$upload_extension =  explode(".", $feature_icon);
$upload_extension = end($upload_extension);
var_dump($upload_extension );
```

[**Live result**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/izdb3j)

Answer (score 7):

Try doing it like this separately:

```
 $upload_extension = explode(".", $feature_icon);
 $upload_extension = end($upload_extension);
```

Comment: Actually, +1 as `end()` expects an argument by reference; er go, not the result of a function call or literal value (*for pedantry, a non-reference returning function call*)

Comment: I hate this strict :(

Answer (score 1):

I probably should know better than to reply to a years old thread, but for what it's worth:

`$upload_extension = end(explode(".", $feature_icon));`

(which doesn't work because end() can only accept arrays defined in a variable, not those returned by functions) can be replaced with:

`$upload_extension = explode ('.', $feature_icon) [count (explode ('.', $feature_icon)) - 1];`

Whether or not you find that more or less elegant than using an intermediary variable to store the array, or using two lines of code (both as suggested above) is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I don't even remember asking this question - heck I don't even use PHP anymore, but thanks for the reply. It might be useful to others!