# move_upload_file doesn't work with extension change

Tags: php

Here is the part of my php file that is responsible for renaming a file and uploading it

```
if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
}

else {
    $filename=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $extension=end(explode('.', $filename));
    $newfilename=$first_name . '_' . $last_name.'.'.$extension;
    move_uploaded_file($filename, 'uploads/' .$newfilename);
}
```

I'm not sure as to why the file is not being uploaded?

Comment: Are you seeing an error, or is the file not ending up where you expect? What is the contents of your $_FILES array?

Comment: No error. Nothing's being uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not directly pass explode returned array in `end()` function. Also verify that `uploads` folder should have valid `read/write` permissions.

You try to get extension from `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`, which is wrong.

> end() -> Parameters ¶ The array. This array is passed by reference
>   because it is modified by the function. This means you must pass it a
>   real variable and not a function returning an array because only
>   actual variables may be passed by reference.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16498292/631652) for reference.

Try this:

```
$filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];   //this param contains name of file
$arr = explode('.', $filename);
$extension=end($arr);
$newfilename=$first_name . '_' . $last_name.'.'.$extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' .$newfilename);
```

Comment: I used the code you provided and it still doesn't upload. It uploads when I don't change the name in the second parameter of move_uploaded_file. It works when the else section is just `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);`

Comment: They must be assigned, because in one part of my code, I'm using php mail() and inside the message I'm using $first_name and $last_name and they're being sent just fine with the variables being filled out in the email. This is the PHP file without your edits http://pastebin.com/Jpm62xED

Comment: Nothing was uploaded when I used the hardcode method

Comment: Email goes through, but nothing is uploaded